If "de-" means "down" or "off" and "sub-" means "under", what is the latin prefix- meaning "up"?
I noted that apparently Latin lacks a prefix meaning up or upwards. Sub can mean "from under" but also "underneath", so is there a specific prefix meaning "up" in Latin  ?
How can I translate the verb "flow up" and "flow down" in Latin ?

See this question for more about how sub- can mean "up". Amazingly, Latin sub- is cognate with English "up"!

Would 'super' work here, with the sense of flowing over rather than up? What is the subject in the sentence you're translating?

I know nothing of Latin, but would an in- prefix be sensible?  Thinking of declination vs. inclination in English.  Or does that have a different origin?

Sub can also mean "up to" when it takes an accusative. (When you move to beneath something, you are generally moving up to it.) Sub tuum praesidium confugimus, up to thy citadel we all flee together.
Sub often means up when it is prefixed to a verb; sublevare means to lift up.
Sursum is an adverb meaning upwards. It is the opposite of deorsum. It derives from sub + versum.
Dr. Traupman's English-Latin dictionary gives a small selection of other ways to say up: comesse, to eat up; conficere, to finish up; corripere, to snatch up. All of these use the prefix cum-, con-, cor-. etc.
Using ex-, we have exsurgere, to rise up. Using ante we have antehac, up till now. Using tenus we have umbilico tenus, up to the belly button.
"Up" is a rich English word with many meanings. I doubt I can find a single Latin word which can serve as a simple substitute for any occasion. In that manner it is similar to many other words in English (and in many other languages).
The Latin word for "to flow down" is defluere, from de meaning "down from above" and fluere meaning "to flow".  I would think that "to flow up" would be suffluere, from sub meaning "up from below" and fluere, but unfortunately, the word suffluere is not attested, and I would hesitate to use any word my readers can't look up in a dictionary. So I would probably use two words, sursum fluere, "to flow upwards".

So if I want to translate "flow up" how should I do ? "Subfluo" ? "Sursum fluere"?

@AndreaValente Can you give an example sentence in which you would find such a phrase?

@AndreaValente, precisely. I have updated my question to answer this directly.

Thank you very much. Theoretically "suffluere" could mean "flow up (from below)" ?

@AndreaValente Theoretically, I would think so. If your Latin is going to be the least bit formal, however, I'd recommend sticking to what's in the dictionary.
